# Proving an inequality with absolute values

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

Can anyone explain the second bullet point on the following [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2888649/607539)?

I am trying to understand how this inequality is proven:

$$\delta(A,B)=|A|+|B|=|A|+|B-C+C|\leq |A|+|C|+|B-C|=\delta(A,C)+\delta(C,B)$$

How does one conclude that the inequality is correct and also how are these absolute values manipulated? If anyone can explain this step by step please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all a useful zero is filled in and then a simple application of the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) follows which is $$|x +  y| \le |x| +|y|$$

In more simple steps: $$\begin{align} |B| &= |B + 0| \\ &= |B + (C-C)| \\ &= |(B-C) + C| \\ &\le |B-C| + |C|\end{align}$$

So it follows: $$|A| + |B| \le |A| + |B-C| + |C|$$

Comment: What bothers me is the fact that he defined the metric space as $\mathbb{R}^2$ and then defined the metric as if it were $\mathbb{R}^1$. Is that a mistake?

Comment: No, the definition $$\delta(A,B)=\begin{cases}
|A|+|B|,  & \text{if $A\neq \lambda B$} \\
|A-B|, & \text{if $A= \lambda B$ for some $\lambda$}
\end{cases}$$ is well defined for $A,B \in \Bbb R^n$. If you are confused about the absolute value: It's a short notation for the euclidean norm, so $$|\cdot| = ||\cdot||_2$$ Maybe if we write the metric as $$\delta(A,B)=\begin{cases}
||A||_2+||B||_2,  & \text{if $A\neq \lambda B$} \\
||A-B||_2, & \text{if $A= \lambda B$ for some $\lambda$}
\end{cases}$$ is more familiar to you?