# Do there exist absolutely homogenous metrics that don’t induce a norm?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

From the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2888192/norm-induced-by-distance-implies-translation-invariant-distance?rq=1#), we have that there exist absolutely homogenous, non translation invariant metrics on $\mathbb{R}^2$ that induce a norm. Does there exist a metric space $(\mathbb{R}^n, d)$ where $d$ is absolutely homogenous but that doesn’t induce a norm $p:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ by $p(x)=d(0,x)$. If not, why not?

Comment: The exact same thing works in any dimension

Comment: I’m asking for one that doesn’t induce a norm.

Comment: I was referring to the answer in the question you linked. It presents a metric that is homogeneous and does not come from a norm

Comment: Right, but that’s not what I’m asking about. The metric presented does still define a norm by considering d(x,0), even though it isn’t the metric induced by that norm. I’m asking if there’s a similar metric that doesn’t define a norm by considering distance from 0.